# I am trying to implement socket with Pusher

Tags: php, android, sockets, pusher

I am trying to implement sockets with pusher. I am using android with laraval but during auth of a private channel, I am getting this error...Auth Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: any reason behind 
this

Here is my source code

```
**HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("Authorization","Bearer "+mToken);
    hashMap.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hashMap.put("Accept", "application/json");
    hashMap.put("Client-id","anyid");
    HttpAuthorizer authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer("https://baseurl.com/laravel-websockets/auth");
    authorizer.setHeaders(hashMap);
    PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions();
    options.setAuthorizer(authorizer);
    options.setEncrypted(true);
    options.setCluster("mt1");
    options.setWsPort(6001);
    options.setWssPort(6001);
    options.setUseTLS(true);
    options.setHost("baseurl.com");
    options.buildUrl("anykey");
    Pusher pusher = new Pusher("anykey",options);
    pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Connection State: "+change.getCurrentState());
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Connection Error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    });
    channel = pusher.subscribePrivate("private-AppointmentChat.12.3", new PrivateChannelEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure(String message, Exception e) {
       Log.i(TAG,"Auth Error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        @Override
        public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String channelName) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Success : "+channelName);
        }
        @Override
        public void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Event : "+event);
        }
    },"AppointmentMessage");**
```

Comment: I had the same issue but em still searching for its solution.

Comment: Can you please post the whole error message? It might contain more information about the error.
I noticed that you are using `https://baseurl.com/laravel-websockets/auth` in your example. Is this the correct url you are trying to use or did you change it for this example?

Comment: i have changed this for posting

Comment: this is not actual url

Comment: https://bleepcare.com/laravel-websockets/auth

Comment: this url i am using